# ActiveRecord: cascading has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, many-to-many, associations

I have a model hierarchy something like

```
class King < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :castles
end

class Castle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :king
  has_many   :residencies
  has_many   :residents, through: :residencies
end
```

The many-to-many association between `Castle` and `Resident` (omitted for brevity) is supported by a `Residency` join-model which `belongs_to` a resident and a castle. This is all pretty familiar.

I was surprised to find that if I want to be able to get all the residents who reside in all of a king's castles, I can actually declare

```
has_many :residents, through: :castles
```

in my `King` model. I've never seen this sort of cascading use of `has_many through`, and I'm wondering if it's at all common.

Comment: This is basic behavior, as documented here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: @Pak Not exactly. In all the examples I've seen (including in the linked guide), the model that fulfills the `through` role is an intermediary that belongs to both other models. In my example, the `residency` model exhibits this basic behavior (in connecting a castle with a resident), but the association between a king and a resident has two intermediary models: castle and residency, and the castle does not belong to the residency, it's just the reverse.

Comment: I agree that this is surprising @ivan. You're right that usually the model specified as argument to `:through` is a join-model. I'm not quite sure, but I seem to remember finding that behavior out at some point as well.